# React-csv not allowing me to change or remove enclosing characters

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to export a csv using react-csv. The documentation says that I should be able to modify the enclosing character with an enclosingCharacter prop, but it doesn't seem to make a difference when I set it. It always uses a quotation mark as the enclosing character. I've tried single quotes, false, null. Nothing works. Ideally, I'd like for there to be no enclosing characters and just use commas for the delimiter. What am I doing wrong?

```
<CSVLink
    data={this.state.csvData}
    filename="sample.csv"
    enclosingCharacter={`'`}
 />
```

Current output looks like this: "data1","data2","data3"

Desired output should look like this: data1,data2,data3

Comment: Could you please show how is your data defined?

Comment: but it seems to be correct when your input is string I guess?

Comment: My data is an array of objects, which according to the documentation, should be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

to get the desired output that you're looking for use the following:

```
<CSVLink
    data={this.state.csvData}
    filename="sample.csv"
    enclosingCharacter=''
 />
```

which should output `data1,data2,data3`